# Setting customErrors attribute

Tags: feature-activation, web-config

When activating a feature on a site I am getting a Runtime Error page that indicates to set customError mode attribute to Off in order to see the error.

I have changed the web.config in my IIS folder for the web application but the error message does not display.  Considering there are other web.config files in the 14 hive is there another one I should edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your page is in _layouts folder, you may need to make similar change to {sharepoint root}\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\web.config as well.

Disclaimer: I would refrain from making a change in this file in production environments.

Comment: agreed.. This is my dev box

Answer (score 0):

I would echo Ashish's comment that you should not make these changes in a production environment. The full details of the error should be getting written to the SharePoint log. I would look for the error details there.

I like the [ULSViewer](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer) utility from Microsoft for this purpose.

Comment: do asp.net runtime errors show up on ULS logs? I have not noticed those and will have to check on that.  It would be great if they did.